# How can I use non-interactive mode of CCRC?

Tags: clearcase-remote-client

I'm using `rcleartool` 8.0.0.6 in windows machine. Is there any way to use `rcleartool` non-interactive mode?

For example, if I type: `rcleartool lsview -s`, the client will ask me to input Server URL, username/password in interactive mode.

Is there anyway to use `rcleartool lsview -s -username [username] -pass [password] -server [server]`?
I want to use that command in my java code, so non-interactive mode should be better?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## ClearTeam 8.x

As mentioned in "[The ClearCase 8.x remote client command-line interface (`rcleartool`)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21594728)":

> `rcleartool` is the command-line interface to the IBM Rational ClearCase remote client (CCRC).
>   This interface, first released as a separate download for compatibility with V7.1.2.x and later releases, is delivered in V8.0.0.3 with the changes that are described in this document.

`rcleartool login` wasn't [caching credentials before (7.x)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21373109).
It should cache those credential now.

The [CR 3508](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewChangeRequest&CR_ID=3508) mentions that enhancement has been delivered June 14th 2013 the RFE (Request for Enhancement):

> In CCRC CLI single-line mode, you should only specifiy your login credentials once.

**Session caching for `rcleartool` was delivered in 8.0.0.3**

That means after one `rcleartool login -lname xxx -server xxx -password xxx`, all other `rcleartool` commands shouldn't need login/password anymore.

---

## ClearCase 7.x

You can try and follow the IBM article "[How to run rcleartool without entering username, password and server URL every time](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21402372)"

It suggests modifying the `rcleartool.bat` script.

### Cause

> Normally when one runs `rcleartool` (not under `rcleartool` prompt), he needs to input username, password and server URL every time.
>
> For instance:

```
rcleartool lsvob -username myusername -password mypassword -server  http://myserver:12080/TeamWeb/services/Team

rcleartool lsview -username myusername -password mypassword -server  http://myserver:12080/TeamWeb/services/Team
```

### Answer

> You can backup the original `rcleartool.bat` (`rcleartool` under UNIX) and then modify that file as follows:
>
> Locate the following line in `rcleartool.bat`

```
"%_JAVACMD%" -Djava.util.logging.config.file="%CCRCCLI%/logging.properties" -cp "%CM_API_DIR%\stpwvcm.jar";"%CM_API_DIR%\stpcmmn.jar";"%CM_API_DIR%\stpcc.jar";"%CM_API_DIR%\remote_core.jar";"%CM_API_DIR%\commons-httpclient-3.0.jar";"%CM_API_DIR%\commons-codec-1.3.jar";"%CCRCCLI%\commons-cli-1.1.jar";"%CM_API_DIR%\icu4j-3_8.jar";"%CM_API_DIR%\commons-logging-1.0.4.jar";"%CCRCCLI%\rcleartool.jar" com.ibm.rational.ccrc.cli.command.ClearWan %*
Add the username, password and server URL at the end

"%_JAVACMD%" -Djava.util.logging.config.file="%CCRCCLI%/logging.properties" -cp "%CM_API_DIR%\stpwvcm.jar";"%CM_API_DIR%\stpcmmn.jar";"%CM_API_DIR%\stpcc.jar";"%CM_API_DIR%\remote_core.jar";"%CM_API_DIR%\commons-httpclient-3.0.jar";"%CM_API_DIR%\commons-codec-1.3.jar";"%CCRCCLI%\commons-cli-1.1.jar";"%CM_API_DIR%\icu4j-3_8.jar";"%CM_API_DIR%\commons-logging-1.0.4.jar";"%CCRCCLI%\rcleartool.jar" com.ibm.rational.ccrc.cli.command.ClearWan %* -username myusername -password mypassword -server  http://myserver:12080/TeamWeb/services/Team
```

> After making the above change, rcleartool can be used without entering a username, password and server URL every time.
>
> For instance,

```
rcleartool lsvob
rcleartool lsview
```

> Note that there is still a need for running `rcleartool` directly (not in `rcleartool` prompt) such as:
>
> - Being able to capture the result with > operator.
> - Being able to run in a batch file.

Comment: Hi @VonC, this setting does not work for 8.0.0.6. If I add the login information in rcleartool.bat as you said, there exists error when I use rcleartool lsview. It says: Unrecoginzed option -username. I'm afraid that rcleartool lsview doesn't support the parameter -username. Do you have any other solutions?

Comment: @crispyfries Sure. I have updated my answer to address ClearTeam 8.x

Comment: Hi @VonC. Thanks for your quick answer. But the caching credential will be expired if it is not used for a time. So if the programs runs a little longer, I have to re-login again. Is there any way to remember that login?

Comment: @crispyfries sure: simply have a job which would, in the same shell session, regularly execute the `rcleartool login -lname xxx -server xxx -password xxx`. I didn't see another way of providing true credential caching though.

Answer (score 2):

The approach for **Clear Case 7.1.X** doesn't work for many cases, for instance on a simple CHECKOUT operation or just launch the **rcleartool CLI**.

That's because the server/login options should come before the others parameters. For instance:
**rcleartool** **co** -server XXX -login me -password 1234 **fileToCheckOut.txt**

So what I suggest is to improve a bit the correction mentioned above to separate the first input parameter given to the batch, representing the **Clear Case** command, from the rest, the parameters for the given command.

So it looks more or less like this in batch :

```
set LOGIN=-server XXX -login me -password 1234
set CMD=%1
set PARAMS=

shift
:loop1
if [%1]==[] goto after_loop
set PARAMS=%PARAMS% %1
shift
goto loop1

:after_loop

"%_JAVACMD%" -Djava.util.logging.config.file="%CCRCCLI%/logging.properties" -cp "%CM_API_DIR%\stpwvcm.jar";"%CM_API_DIR%\stpcmmn.jar";"%CM_API_DIR%\stpcc.jar";"%CM_API_DIR%\remote_core.jar";"%CM_API_DIR%\commons-httpclient-3.0.jar";"%CM_API_DIR%\commons-codec-1.3.jar";"%CCRCCLI%\commons-cli-1.1.jar";"%CM_API_DIR%\icu4j-3_8.jar";"%CM_API_DIR%\commons-logging-1.0.4.jar";"%CCRCCLI%\rcleartool.jar" com.ibm.rational.ccrc.cli.command.ClearWan %CMD% %LOGIN% %PARAMS%
```

Ugly as the devil himself, but it works **for most cases**.
You can perform simple tasks like you could before, plus Check-outs/ins and similiar.

What you **CAN'T** do still is to launch the rcleartool CLI and use the **help** command.
It requests me a password, and even if I enter, it fails.

**edit:** comparison on shift snipet was failing when receiving parameters with quotes and spaces in it.

Comment: Interesting alternative to my answer. +1