# Porting perl script to graphical user interfaces for clearcase

Tags: c#, windows, perl, clearcase

We got quite a number of perl scripts running in our environment. Even creating branch and view for it are done via script. Now we have in the process of porting this perl script to GUI based environment. What language do you prefer for this ? We have some inhouse tools return in C# (developer are not with us). This may also get ported.

ENV -> Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even for GUI, perl remains the safest road (as you saw in "[How can I interact with ClearCase from Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2273896/6309)")

but it also can depend on your ClearCase version: with 8.X and ClearTeam (new CCRC), the [CLI rcleartool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21577362/6309) (also [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18506213/6309)) can be wrapped by any language you want (through wrapping system calls).

The other option is the Java API:

- for [ClearCase 7.X](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21117682)
- for [ClearCase 8.x and CM API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21566474)

Comment: Our Env is 7.x. Perl will make life easier. however I have few questions on the same. How easy GUI Development in Perl ? found wxPerl, Perl-Tk, just checking in case you know better about this. Can this be complied to exe ?

Comment: You can use any language that supports running command-lines (i.e. cleartool).

Comment: I need to start from zero, any suggestion would be helpful Vb6/c#/ Vc++/perl-tk ?

Comment: found below --> •Visual Basic: Objected-oriented programming
•C#: Generics and closures
•Ruby (on Rails): The power of MVC design

Comment: this too, If you mean Windows GUI and "better" means "easiest but still pretty capable", then for simple utilities, I vote for VB6. 
 If you mean Windows GUI and "better" means "Most powerful and yet still relatively easy" then I vote for C#.
 If you mean Cross-Platform GUI and "better" means "is actaully cross-platform" I would suggest Java.