# Numeric ClearCase Activity IDs

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have a question about ClearCase activity IDs.

By default they are just strings, but is there any way to force them to be numerical ids? It does not appear to be a simple setting anywhere, so I thought perhaps there is some background script that has to be triggered if this is possible at all.

I want this to be automated/managed by the system, not left up to developers to plug in whatever id they want.

Thoughts? I'm using ClearCase 8 (UCM) on Windows. As well, most of our developers use the GUI as opposed to command line, if that makes a difference.

Comment: For what reason? I'm wondering what happens when developers name it whatever they want

Comment: @TamirGefen: I'm trying to standardize activity ids so I can do things like cross-reference them in my bug tracking software. I'd like to be able to indicate that a bug was fixed in activity 1234 as opposed to something like activity id this_is_the_activity_name. It is just more portable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That wouldn't be covered by ClearCase directly.

If you are using full ClearCase (as opposed to CCRC or ClearTeam), you could deploy a wrapper for `cleartool`, which would intercept a [`cleartool mkact`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkactivity.htm) command and provide the right name according to your policy.

For [ClearTeam, you would wrap `rcleartool`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22146929/6309).

But in both cases, that would be a command-line solution.

---

One other alternative would be to control the activity name, through a pre-op mkact trigger.

Comment: ClearCase with ClearQuest UCM-enabled also forces the users to use numeric activity ID

Comment: @VonC: Yeah, I think a pre-op mkact trigger was something along the lines of what I was thinking. I'll look into that. Thanks!

Comment: @VonC - I meant to ask a follow-up question on this - how do you suggest actually managing the numbers? Can ClearCase somehow do this for you, or so you need your own number management mechanism?

Comment: @ChrisC you will have to name your activity following the naming/numbering convention you see fit. ClearCase doesn't force one, except when linked with ClearQuest.