# ClearCase Linux GUI error comparing/checkin-out/describe/

Tags: linux, user-interface, clearcase

We have ClearCase Server (version 7.0.1.1-IFIX02) installed on a Linux Server "SRV1" (vobs, views and license). The development environment is on another linux server "SRV2". On this server is also ClearCase installed (7.0.1). We access to the views through the ClearCase GUI installed on the development server.

We can access to the GUI without any problem and do any action with the files and directories on the current path where we've started the GUI. But after moving to other directory in the file browser of the GUI, we cannot do checkouts, comparison, describe, ... A windows appear with the "Transcript":

```
 /bin/sh: ./grpXXXXX: No existe el fichero o el directorio
```

Where `XXXXX` is 5 digits number different on each action.

The fact is, when using ClearCase GUI on the ClearCase server "SRV1", we don't have such problem.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to debug the situation is to revert back to the command line.

If you have ClearCase 7.x, use `cleartool`. ([ClearCase 8.x, use rcleartool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18506213/6309)):

```
cd /path/to/your/view/.../yourFolder
cleartool ls
```

That should give you the current state of that folder and its elements, as well as the selection rules which apply from the config spec of the view.
Note that the issue can vary depending on the nature of said view (snapshot or dynamic, even with ClearTeam Explorer 8.x, since it does support dynamic views as well, and not just web views)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quickly answer!

I solved it!

One colleague suggest me to see owner and group of /tmp. Someone or somehow (this is another question...) has change the /tmp rights, owner and group. Then the development user couldn't write on /tmp. Apparently ClearCase need to write, temporary, certain files "grpXXXXX" when using GUI. So I change to root-root with drwxrwxrwx rights:

```
 chown root:root /tmp
 chmod 777 /tmp
```

And it works!

Regards,

Comment: Well, depending on the operations and files in question, the /tmp directory (Or the directory pointed to by the TMP environment variable, which is usually /tmp) is used for container creation and/or construction. So, you can have little surprises if that directory has odd permissions. And like VonC said, when all else fails, use the CLI. The error messages are much better.