# How to create a clear case UCM job in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, build-process, clearcase

I am new to ClearCase UCM and my first task in this is to create job in jenkins. So I have installed the ClearCase plugin in jenkins but when try to create a new job, I am not getting any clue on what to fill values for the fields, View Tag, View Path and Stream Selector. Searched a lot on google for an example but couldn't find one.

So could you please give me some examples values or any article which you are aware of which explains this in details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "ClearCase UCM job" in Jenkins simply means a job which will use the sources visible (selected) by a (preferable snapshot ones if you are doing some build in it)

That means you nead:

- an UCM stream which selects the UCM components you need
- a [UCM snapshot view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1367656/6309) associated to that stream, which will give you the view tag, view path (anywhere you want on the slave) and stream selector (`stream:aStream@/vobs/aPVob` if unix, `stream:aStream@\aPVob` if Windows)

Comment: I still didn't understand it. Sorry I am very new to ClearCase. In eclipse I did create a view using the server URL, so is it similar to this in jenkins as well?

Comment: @GuruKulki you have to create a view indeed. Did you create an UCM view with Eclipse? If so, you can use it in Jenkins.

Comment: Yes, I did create a UCM view

Comment: I can see that view in ClearCase Navigator

Comment: @GuruKulki Then you can use it in Jenkins (if the Jenkins slave is in the same OS as your view) Are you on Windows or Linux as a ClearCase client? And your Jenkins slave, is it on Windows, Linux? What version of ClearCase are you using?

Comment: I am not sure of the ClearCase version, but jenkins and view both are on Windows

Comment: When I run the job in jenkins, I get an error as [Test Project] $ cleartool desc -fmt %[found_bls]Xp stream:XYZ@null

Comment: @GuruKulki ClearCase might use `rcleartool` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18506213/6309). Check your `PATH`. `@null` is problematic: the stream name should be `stream:XYZ@\aPVob`, with `aPVob` the name of the pvob which has that stream.

Comment: @GuruKulki If you select the properties of your view in the ClearCase Navigator, you will see the name of its associated stream.

Comment: @GuruKulki For `rcleartool` `PATH`: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21598728

Comment: sorry, I was off from work, couldn't reply on weekends.. Can you please give me some example values for View Tag, View Path and Stream Selector fields?

Comment: @GuruKulki You can see examples of UCM views in the example section of mkview: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkview.htm (`cleartool mkview -stream java_int@/vobs/core_projects -tag java_int /usr1/views/java_int.vws`). Also in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21121208 (look for examples using -stream). Or in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21152760 (look for the section "Create the Views that will be associated to the streams:")

Comment: Sorry, I stopped working clearcase and moved to GIT. thanks for your time and information. I will use this once I start clearcase again.

Comment: @GuruKulki Great choice! I compare ClearCase and git here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/645008/6309

Comment: Just one doubt on git, I have a create a local repository on my laptop and did associate it with any remote repo, so just wanted to know, can I create a jenkin job for my local repo?

Comment: @GuruKulki Sure: as long as your Jenkins job has the path of that git repo, it can populate a Jenkins workspace with the latest of that repo master branch.

Comment: Thanks VonC for your time and help. I am able to setup the test job on jenkins with GIT local repo

Answer (score 0):

The [ClearCase UCM Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+UCM+Plugin) is made specifically to support UCM as opposed to the ClearCase plugin which you're asking to. The ClearCase plugin originally didn't support anything but base ClearCase - and it had it's UCM features glued on along the evolution.

The ClearCase UCM plugin does everything for you. Just specify the steam and the promotion level of the baselines you want to build and the rest is automated from there on. No need to create views first, the plugin will do it for you.